# insert into MySQL with URL String

Tags: php, mysql, http

Cant seem to get this to work. could some one please point me out into the right direction with an example how to fi this. thank you.
i need this url
domain.com/script.php?from=1123&message=1234454

to insert velues into my table

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');

mysql_select_db('dbname');

$sql = "insert into table (from, message) values ('".$_GET['from']."','".$_GET['message']."')"; 
if(!$sql){ 
echo "Error " . mysql_error(); }
else{ echo "Success"; }

?>
```

Comment: There's nothing there to actually insert into the database - you're just generating a string of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
 mysql_query($sql);
```

So it actually adds to the db at the moment you are just creating a string

Comment: No, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query`, especially not when none of the parameters are properly escaped. [Do it properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html). Posting answers like this is only teaching dangerous techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) to actually execute the query.

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');

mysql_select_db('dbname');

$from    = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['from']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['message']);

// TODO: check that $from and $message are not empty and are valid

$sql    = "insert into table (from, message) values ('$from','$message')"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);  // This actually executes the query on the server

if(!$result) { 
    echo "Error " . mysql_error();
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
```

The call to [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is very important as well.  Without it, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Also, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  You should switch to [Mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO_Mysql](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' ('from', 'message') values ('111111','223232')' at line 1

Comment: Add `echo $sql;` before you run the query.  What is the full output?

Comment: I think the problem is that you have to use backticks (`) around table, from, and message, not single quotes.

Comment: Strings get enclosed in single or double quotes, SQL identifiers like table and column names (can) get enclosed in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if the variables are set.

```
    if(isset($_GET['from'],$_GET['message'])){
       $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');

       mysql_select_db('dbname',$con);

       $from    = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['from']);
       $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['message']);

// TODO: check that $from and $message are not empty and are valid

$sql    = "insert into table (from, message) values ('$from','$message')"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result) {  echo "Error " . mysql_error(); } 
else {  
  echo "Success"; 
  mysql_close($con);
}

}else{die();}
```

Comment: The last thing the internet needs is yet another example using `mysql_query`. Please don't do this.